# Iphone imagelibrary Doubts

Tags: iphone

i have view controller which contains a button which show the image library ,if the user tap the image,the select image will display in the same view with the button ,but i want to show this image in another class ?(view controller).my code is

```
-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    if((UIButton *) sender == choosePhotoBtn) {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    }   
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

it shows the image in the same view,but my need is to show it in another view.How to dod this.

Comment: Just pass the imageView.image to the viewController to where you want show the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the Image in a UIImage object and pass it to the viewController you want

In your Current View Controller

.h declare the a UIImage object

```
UIImage *selectedImage;
```

In .m file

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   selectedImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    imageView.image = selectedImage;
}
```

Pass it to the viewController you want

```
YourViewController *viewObj = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
viewObj.imageToBePassed = selectedImage;
//You should synthesize this object imageToBePassed
[self viewObj animated:YES];
[viewObj release];
```

Comment: hii,u r correct,but there is a problem in navigation  [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; it will show the sameviewcontroller after selection of image from library,

Comment: you can even pass the imagePath and retrive that from other controller 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4314524/1059705

Comment: @WhySoSerious i for this error while adding this code YourViewController *viewObj = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
viewObj.imageToBePassed = selectedImage;
//You should synthesize this object imageToBePassed
[self viewObj animated:YES];
[viewObj release]; "incompatible pointer type assining to UIImageView From UIImage

Comment: @stackiphone you are assigning a UIImage to a UImageView.. imageToBePassed is a UIImage not a UIImageView